# Re-use jsdoc's @typedef into swagger-jsdoc

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, jsdoc

### Context :

- `node.js`
- Open Api 3
- `express`, `swagger-jsdoc`

I use *jsdoc*'s `@typdef` to have *Intellisens* autocompleting with *VSCode* :

```js
/** @typedef {number} Id */

/**
 * @typedef Data
 * @property {Id} requestId
 */

/** @type {Data} */
const data = { id: 42 };
```

### Issue :

I've just installed `swagger-jsdoc` and set it up into `express`.

Now i would like to re-use the `@typedef Data` and `@typedef Id` created above into swagger route description as following :

```js
/**
 * @swagger
 * 
 * /cats:
 *      get:
 *          description: Search any cat from all parameters in query
 *          produces:
 *              - application/json
 *          parameters:
 *              - name : requestId
 *                in: query
 *                required: false
 *                type: Id <========================== HERE
 *         responses:
 *              200:
 *                  description: cats
 *                  schema:
 *                      type: Data <================== HERE
 */
 router.get('/cats', catsFilter);
```

This sample is not working.

Do you know a way to re-use jsdoc's `@typedef` into `swagger-jsdoc` ?